# maximum number of simultaneous users for xampp in windows

Tags: php

i am working on creating a web application with php and mysql in a xampp server in windows. I want to know the maximum number of users it can handle at a time. If i am using the wrong technology , please suggest a good one

Comment: Very difficult question, that totally depends on your machine. Regardless of what number comes out, you probably don't have a bandwidth that is good enough to handle the users. Get a hosted server instead.

Answer (score 0):

The only option i see in you're case would be to benchmark you're site/app .

This can be achived with [ab apache benchmark module](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html) , and you'll have an ideea of how you're server will handle users ( [example of usage here](http://www.macgeekery.com/tips/troubleshooting/stress-test_apache_with_ab) ). ab.exe should be located at `xampp\apache\bin\ab.exe` .